# How do I set up a basic IPv6 video stream using VLC

Tags: ipv6, stream, video

I'm teaching a class IPv6 and would like to create a lab for them to see the true benefit of ipv6 multicasting in action.

I created a multicast address for myself

ff15::1 (where ff is multicast, 1 is transient, no rsvp, and 5 is site scope). I then gave myself a group id of 1.

I get an "No route to host" error when trying to start the stream. Any ideas greatly appreciated.

ps: I know almost nothing about streaming.

```
...
main debug: net: connecting to [[FF15::1]]:1234
main warning: [FF15::1] port 1234 : No route to host
access_output_udp error: failed to create raw UDP socket
main warning: no sout access module matching "udp" could be loaded
main debug: TIMER module_need() : 1.171 ms - Total 1.171 ms / 1 intvls (Avg 1.171 ms)
stream_out_standard error: no suitable sout access module for `udp/ts://[FF15::1]'
...
```

Surely if its a brand new multicast, there won't be a route to host until someone listens?

Comment: I know very little about IPv6 myself - but did you give the interface a unicast address as well?

Comment: It also might be worth mentioning what OS you're using.

Comment: Does your system have an IPv6 address?  Can you should us (a) your interface configuration, and (b) your IPv6 routing table(s)?

Comment: Do not configure the NIC's interfaces for anything. If you're using ancient OSes you have to finagle them, but for anything half modern you should not.

Comment: I'm using OS X 10.6.8

Comment: Does it work if you add the interface ID? In Linux this would look like `rtp://[ff15::1]%eno1`. I don't know how Mac name their interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Server:

1. Open VLC, File->Streaming
2. Add files to be streamed, preferably something that doesn't need to be transcoded.
3. Stream button.
4. Next.
5. New Destionation -> "RTP / MPEG Transport Stream". Add button.
6. Address `[ff15::1]` (with the brackets!)
7. Uncheck Active Transcoding. Next. Stream.

Client:

1. Open VLC, File-> Open Network Stream...
2. URL: `rtp://[ff15::1]`
3. Play

Works like a charm if both are IPv6 enabled and the network supports multicast (anything in the last 10 years basically). The UDP streaming hasn't been updated in a while, it probably doesn't support IPv6, but I don't know that for certain.

Note: One the clients are playing the stream the server can stop and start a new stream usually without interruption... So once the initial list of media is done playing repeat the Server instructions and the client should start playing the new media.

Comment: I'm still getting a "no route to host" in the log file... (I'm on OS X, by the way, so my screens are slightly different)

Comment: Are you running OSX 10.2 (Jaguar) or higher?

Comment: Snow Leopard...

Comment: And you're using RTP as UDP has "poor" IPv6 support?

Comment: I think it has something to do with my machine not realizing that I'm trying to stream to a multicast address that I created. I think its looking in the neighbor table instead of just streaming it to the network.

Comment: This works for a friend of mine running VLC 2.0. What version of VLC are you running? Have you made any changes to the computer's IPv6 configuration at all?